# Siri Custom Intent UI Add custom button with action

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, siri, sirishortcuts

I am working on an app with Siri custom intent ui, where I have created custom intent, it will respond to the user with the configured Siri command, and It is working perfectly

> The Siri response I attached as a screenshot, I am facing a
> challenge here, there is a button called Open Maps created in
> IntentViewController and it has target action where It is opening
> Apple maps, but when I tap the open maps button it is not listening
> the target action and wherever I tap It is opening the actual app, the
> control is not coming to target action method.

**How do I achieve that in Siri Custom UI Intent?**

[image]